# How to manually have ACRA send pending reports (offline use)

Tags: android, crash, offline, acra

We're in this situation where our clients use our mobile application offline 95% of the time. At the end of their work day, when they get back to the office, they synchronize all data with our servers while they have network connectivity.

We have ACRA set up with the AcraHttpSender plugin to attempt sending us the crash reports directly, however this usually fails because they're using the application offline and ACRA stores the reports instead.

From what I understand the pending reports will only be sent by ACRA when the application is **restarted**, through ACRA.init. The problem is the users have no reason to restart the application at the end of their work day (while they have network connectivity). I have to stress that the users are complete tech illiterates, our clients made that clear to us.

So, we would really need to be able to tell ACRA to send us any pending crash reports it has during the short time network connectivity is available. Without user interaction of any kind. I was thinking maybe in the onCreate function of our main activity.

However I've been looking at documentation and other people asking the same question for a while and haven't found anything obvious. Is this possible?

EDIT: This is the current working code with the suggestion made by @F43nd1r and @CommonsWare. It wasn't working for me with 5.4.0, but with 5.5.1 it is.

Gradle

```
def acraVersion = '5.5.1'
implementation "ch.acra:acra-core-ktx:$acraVersion"
implementation "ch.acra:acra-http:$acraVersion"
implementation "ch.acra:acra-advanced-scheduler:$acraVersion"
implementation "ch.acra:acra-toast:$acraVersion"
```

Initialization

```
    initAcra {
        setBuildConfigClass(BuildConfig::class.java)
        setReportFormat(StringFormat.JSON)
        plugin<ToastConfigurationBuilder> {
            setResText(R.string.acra_crash_text)
            setLength(Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            setEnabled(true)
        }
        plugin<HttpSenderConfigurationBuilder> {
            setUri("${BuildConfig.protocol}://${BuildConfig.host}/${BuildConfig.codemrc}/acra")
            setHttpMethod(HttpSender.Method.POST)
            setBasicAuthLogin("acra")
            setBasicAuthPassword("******")
            setEnabled(true)
        }
        plugin<SchedulerConfigurationBuilder> {
            setRequiresNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
            setRestartAfterCrash(true)
            setResReportSendSuccessToast(R.string.acra_report_sent_text)
            setEnabled(true)
        }
    }

    // Turn this on to obtain more messages in the log to debug ACRA
    ACRA.DEV_LOGGING = BuildConfig.DEBUG
```

Comment: They have an [`AdvancedServerScheduler`](https://www.acra.ch/javadoc/5.4.0/org/acra/scheduler/AdvancedSenderScheduler.html) that uses `JobScheduler` to upload reports. Perhaps look into integrating that and using a configuration that says that you need a network connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CommonsWare stated in the comments, [AdvancedSenderScheduler](https://www.acra.ch/javadoc/latest/org/acra/scheduler/AdvancedSenderScheduler.html) is the way to go.

Example usage:

```
implementation "ch.acra:acra-advanced-scheduler:5.5.1"
```

```
@AcraScheduler(requiresNetworkType = JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED,
               requiresBatteryNotLow = true)
```

---

In case you're not satisfied with `AdvancedSenderScheduler` options, you could also register your own [SenderScheduler](https://www.acra.ch/javadoc/latest/org/acra/scheduler/SenderScheduler.html), but that should rarely be necessary.

Comment: Thanks F43nd1r. Just so I understand clearly, does this advanced scheduler periodically check for network connectivity, and then if it detects it, will send the stored/unsent reports? If so, how often does it check for network connectivity? This will work without restarting the application? I added the advanced scheduler like your example, turned off wifi, made the application crash, turned the wifi back on and waiting almost 30 minutes now, but the report hasn't been sent.

Comment: I have added the BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission in the manifest but it didn't help

Comment: There was a bug. Dunno how it went unnoticed so long. Anyway, use 5.5.1 which contains a fix for this.

Comment: To answer your question: It does not check periodically. It's the other way around: The system calls your app as soon as required conditions are met. This should happen within seconds to minutes after e.g. a network connection is established. You don't need to add that permission.

Comment: I was using 5.4.0 to avoid the AndroidX/SDK 28 requirement because I'm not sure the clients are using Android 9. Nevertheless I have tried it with 5.5.1 and it is indeed working (see edited question with current code). I will suggest the clients update to Android 9. Thank you very much.Last question: In setRequiresNetworkType why do I have to convert the JobRequest.NetworkType to int using .ordinal. In the examples I found online the conversion doesn't appear to be required, the enum is used directly.

Comment: Please note that sdk29 is the *target* sdk, not the minimum sdk, which is still 14. No need to update for your clients. Sorry for the outdated examples. Constants should be `JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED`, not using JobRequest.